# How to create a pandas DataFrame column based on the existence of values

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
aw = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],
columns=['A','B','C'])

print(aw)
>>>
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
```

I want to create a column D based on values of column C

If Value is in top 20 %, set value of Das 0.04

If Value is in top 40 % and less than top 20%, set value of D as 0.03

If Value is in top 60 % and less than top 20%, set value of D as 0.02

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try

```
def percentile(x):
if x>df.C.quantile(0.8):
    return 0.04
elif x>df.C.quantile(0.6) and x<= df.C.quantile(0.8):
    return 0.03
elif x>df.C.quantile(0.4) and x<= df.C.quantile(0.6):
    return 0.02
else:
    return None

df['D'] = df['C'].apply(percentile)
```

Like suggested by Mayank Porwal, you can replace `df.C.quantile(0.8)` with `numpy.percentile(df.C, 80)`

Comment: You can also use `numpy.percentile` to achieve the same thing.